# How to make a dictionary between vectors and numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a dictionary between some graph vertices labeled as (1,2,3...) or (a,b,c) and their positions when this graph is embedded in three dimensions. For example, consider the cubic lattice and the map between positions (i,j,k) to number i+(j-1)*4+(k-1)*16. How does one store this map? I tried the cell array
c=[];

but this does not let me append vectors like (i,j,k,  i+(j-1)*4+(k-1)*16) to an array? The question is of course more general than this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mapping Z → R<sup>3</sup>. This can be simply implemented as a 2D matrix. Let's assume that the vertex labels are integers in the range [1,100]. Create the matrix:

```matlab
map = nan(100,3);
```

Now `map(i,:)` is the 3D vector associated to node `i`. You can assign a new value to a node, but you can also append new nodes:

```matlab
map(end+1,:) = [1,2,3];
```

But do note that assigning to a node outside of the map will cause zero-valued nodes to be inserted in between the existing entries and the new one:

```matlab
map(200,:) = [1,2,3];
```

will cause nodes 100-199 to be `[0,0,0]`.

---

To assign the vector `[i,j,k]` to node number `i+(j-1)*4+(k-1)*16`, for all `i`, `j`, `k` in the range [1,4], you can use `ndgrid`:

```matlab
[i,j,k] = ndgrid(1:4,1:4,1:4);
i = i(:);
j = j(:);
k = k(:);
map(i+(j-1)*4+(k-1)*16,:) = [i,j,k];
```

---

The above breaks down if vertices are identified with other than integer values in a relatively compact range. If your identifiers are arbitrarily larger integers, floating-point numbers, letters, or words, then the simplest solution would be to use a [`containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html). This is orders of magnitude slower, though. I would suggest to use integers to represent nodes.